# GWT 2.5.1 application with erroneous behavior in older versions of Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, gwt, listbox

### EDIT:

Furthermore, I should point out that this bug does not appear to happen whenever I'm running the application in hosted/devmode. Only when I do a full compile on it and run it in tomcat does the problem appear.

---

I've been tasked to investigate and possibly fix an issue we're having with a listbox widget misbehaving in certain versions of Chrome. I've discovered through testing that this appears to only be happening in Chrome/Chromium 33 and 34 (the versions me and my manager are using on Linux Mint), and is working as expected in Chrome 35 and Chromium 37. I don't have an older Windows version of Chrome to test against.

All I can say about the problem in question is that clicking on a listbox in certain areas/states of the application cause a toolbar item (completely unrelated to the listbox) to become "active", and the listbox opens and closes very quickly. Analyzing the code of the webpage shows that the class of that HTML element gets changed to add a 'selected' class when I hold the mouse down on the listbox, and reverts back to un-selected when I lift the mouse. Needless to say we have no idea where to even look in the application for something like this, especially where it's only happening on Chrome versions older than 35.

I've been asked to find out what exactly might have changed in Chrome to "fix" this bug, and if I can figure out how to fix this quirk in older versions of Chrome. The Chrome 35 changelog makes reference to something called "Unprefixed Shadow DOM". A quick search for "Shadow DOM GWT" tells me that GWT 2.5.1 has an experimental component/feature called Elemental which makes use of Shadow DOM.

Comment: What handlers are attached to this ListBox? What do they do?

Comment: The only handler is a ChangeHandler that changes the value of an enum type according to the value selected in the listbox, and alters the refresh rate of a clock used for updating the interface.

Comment: Shadom dom is unrelated to this, its a new feature that GWT is not using (except in elemental, and elemental isnt used by ListBox or the rest of gwt-user).